# systemjs - Loading jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, systemjs

Can someone tell me how to load a simple javascript file into the browser using SystemJS.

I am trying to load in jquery from my node_modules folder using the following syntax-:

```
packages: {
      app: {
        main: './js/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
        'jquery': {
        main: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
    }
    }
```

But whenever I write the following lines in my browser

```
$(document).ready(function(){alert("Hello");});
```

My entire SystemJS configuration is -:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'jquery':                    'npm:jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',      
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './js/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

I get an error that $ is not defined.

**How do you load a simple .js file into an the browser using SystemJS ?**

Comment: did you try using `jQuery` in place of `$`?

Comment: @jkris Yup same effect. jQuery not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is both correct and expected because jQuery, being a well written, environment friendly library does not unconditionally inject itself into the global namespace, `window` in a browser if a suitable loader is available. SystemJS detects that jQuery is an AMD module and provides the correct wrappers for it to register itself properly using the AMD `define` api.

This means that you need to import it in order to use it.

The following code will work under TypeScript and Babel

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$(document).ready(() => {
  alert("Hello");
});
```

If you want access to jquery in your browser console. You can do the following

```
// In your browser tools console
SystemJS.import('jquery').then(({default}) => { 
  window.$ = default;
});
```